# Wildfly 8 security domain works for a simple app but not for a more complex one

Tags: java, wildfly-8, java-ee-7

I am altering an existing Java EE 7 web application to use the standard Java EE security domain mechanism to authenticate against Active Directory.  I began by creating a simple proof of concept web app to test things out and to get the Wildfly config working, then I applied the changes to the main app.  I'm now in the situation where the test app works but the main app does not.

How do I get the main app to work with the security domain properly?  How can I diagnose this issue?  What can interfere with the security process?

Here is my realm and domain config in standalone.xml:

```xml
<security-realms>
    <!-- Default realms omitted -->
    <security-realm name="ActiveDirectoryRealm">
        <authentication>
            <ldap connection="MyAD" base-dn="OU=Test Users,OU=AU,DC=company,DC=int">
                <username-filter attribute="sAMAccountName"/>
            </ldap>
        </authentication>
    </security-realm>
</security-realms>
<outbound-connections>
    <ldap name="MyAD" url="ldap://company.int" search-dn="CN=Wildfly AS,OU=Service Accounts,OU=AU,DC=company,DC=int" search-credential="xxx"/>
</outbound-connections>

<!-- Skip many lines -->

<security-domain name="active-directory" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="sufficient">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
            <module-option name="realm" value="ActiveDirectoryRealm"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

And here is my jboss-web.xml file (same in both apps):

```xml
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>active-directory</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

And finally the security bits of web.xml (same in both apps except the URL patterns constrained):

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Unauthenticated Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/font/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/lib/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/partials/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/Login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/NoAccess.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Some facts about the apps:

- Both apps are using a Servlet 3.1 web.xml file and are packaged as a WAR.
- Both apps activate the Undertow and EJB subsystems, while the main app also activates JPA.
- I have deployed both apps to the same Wildfly 8.2 instance running on my local machine.
- The main app uses Spring (as we use Spring-Data and Spring-MVC) as well as EJB, while the test app does not use Spring.

The test app works perfectly, but the main app always fails to log in (I get redirected to form-error-page).  I turned TRACE logging on for `org.jboss.security` but all I get when I try to log in is this:

```
2015-07-22 13:36:54,903 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-1) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

For extra strangeness points, I can set the security domain value in jboss-web.xml to either `active-directory` or `java:/jaas/active-directory` and both work, however using the prefix in the main app causes it to fail to start.  I know [the prefix is no longer supported in Wildfly 8](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-ChangesyouneedtomakeforSecurity) but not sure why the behaviour is different between the two apps.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions, it's all greatly appreciated!

Comment: >the standard Java EE security domain mechanism - FYI, that's not any Java EE standard but a JBoss specific one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing... it turns out the problem was in my login form.  I thought they were the same between the two apps but the main app had a leading space in the names of the input fields.